# Select Multiple Items in CustomPivotViewer of Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, pivot

I'm thinking of CTR-Clicking each item to build up an array to add.... or even more fancy, drag select an area of items (don't think this is possible tho).

I'm aware of the custom events such as ItemDoubleClicked, but is there something like ItemSingleClick, where I can check if the CTR/SHIFT key is being pressed before executing an action.

Comment: I'm currently using CTR-double click to execute custom function, if there is no answer for next few days, I'll close the thread with answer "unable to detect single click event for items in PivotViewer"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is no possible way to customise the pivot since it is not open source... and the only method I can use is the doubleClick (plus match a keyboard key)...

I don't even like the way it zooms in right away after single clicking on an item.

I'm still open to suggestions (who knows... the pivot will probably still evolve), but otherwise, this thread I'm closing.